# WiX 3.7 UI not linking correctly

Tags: wix, wix-extension, wix3.7

Newbie to WiX here...  I have created my WiX installer package, and it installs all features correctly.  Then I try adding a UI to it with the following:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" /> 
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

and I link with "light -ext WixUIExtension -cultures:en-us".  It finds this extension because it will give an error  if I try it with a non-existent name, but the resulting msi package is only 30kb.  I assume this should be slightly larger if the UI extension is correctly linked?

When I run the msi, it just gives the normal progress bar and no additional UI that I am expecting from WixUI_Minimal.

All the references seem to claim that a simple UIRef is all you need to get a UI when the package is linked correctly...  Is there a known way for the linking to not happen correctly with no errors being thrown (even when I link with -pedantic)?

Comment: Did u add a reference for the UI dll?

Answer (score 1):

The MSI may not be significantly larger when you add the UI. There are not many graphics provided by default. However, if you are not seeing UI during the install, that does mean the UI is not being linked in.

The `UIRef` needs to be in a referenced section. The first section the linker starts with is the `Product` element. If your `UIRef` is a child of `Product` then it will definitely get linked in. The linker then walks through all the references in the `Product` element (anything that ends in a `Ref` is a reference as are many other attributes) looking for needed elements in other `Fragment` elements. The linker then pulls in everything in those `Fragment` elements. For example:

```
<Product>
   <DirectoryRef Id='TARGETDIR' />
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Source='SourceDir' />

    <BinaryRef Id='icon' />
<Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <Binary Id='icon' Source='path\to\my.ico' />
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
   <UIRef Id='WixUI_Minimal' />
</Fragment>
```

In the above example, the first three sections will be included by the linker. The section with `UIRef='WixUI_Minimal'` however is left out because nothing references it. To fix it, the `UIRef` could be moved to any of the other `Fragment` elements.

To test, try moving your `UIRef` to your `Product` element. If that doesn't work, provide more details in your question about where your `UIRef` is for us to help further.

Comment: Hey, what I did work out this morning after starting with a very very simple example and trying to see where this went wrong is that it was how I was trying to build this project.  I have a batch file in which I ran candle on it twice with -arch x86 then -arch x64 then linked both obj files to their own msi.  If I run light, then candle immediately on the 32 bit one it will give me a correct MSI with the minimal UI.  But the 64 bit one is still apparently incorrect.  It is possible to build a 64 bit msi and link it with WixUIExtension on a 32 bit platform, is it not?